# HP laptop doesn't boot, endlessly restarts

Tags: windows-xp, boot, reboot

My HP Pavilion dv9000 laptop (running Windows XP) won't boot - it just keeps going into a restart cycle.

I've tried to turn it on without the hard drive inside but I still get to the same rebooting sequence. It doesn't even show the BIOS details before it restarts. I'm also unable to boot into safe mode as the computer doesn't get that far before restarting.

The restarting happens within a matter of two seconds - it doesn't have time to display anything on the screen hence why it does not display the BIOS. This keeps repeating until I take the battery out. Not much more happens than that.

Comment: Please add the model number to your post.

Comment: If it doesn't show BIOS, how do you know it restarts? Have you tried tapping F8 as it starts to get to the boot menu? Some more detail would help us help you.

Comment: because it restarts with a matter of 2 seconds it doest have time to display anthing on the screen hence why it does display bios. i mean what other details can i give u i turn it on it restarts after 2 seconds and keeps repeating this untill i take battery out not much more happens than that

Comment: dv9000 series suffered from all kinds of motherboard failures, some can be repaired, some not...http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260674058980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the graphics chip on the motherboard is faulty, and needs replacing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Power off the laptop.
2. Power on the laptop.
3. As soon as you see the rotating loading circle, press and hold the Power Button until the computer shuts off.
4. Repeat this process a few times until you see the "Preparing Automatic Repair" screen.
5. Now you want to let the laptop boot to the "Automatic Repair" screen.
6. Click "Advanced Options" and then select "Troubleshoot".
7. Here you want to select "Refresh your PC", if you do not wish to erase data, or "Reset your PC" to erase all data and restore your system.
8. From here just follow the screen instructions until the recovery is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the battery and Changer out, hold the power button for 10 seconds then release and hold the power button for another 10 seconds, plug the charger in leave battery out and try and boot it.

If it powers on then plug battery back in and relax....

Comment: thanks but that didnt work it still reboots whole time

Answer (score 0):

Check the cooling fan is working and vents are not blocked or full of fluff/dust.

The maintenance manual for your laptop is [here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01311536.pdf)
It describes how to access the fan assembly. I use a paintbrush to loosen dust and just blow it away, canned air and vacuum cleaners can be too harsh.

Comment: fans seems to spin ip ok and not much dust there at all but i just used compressed air to get rid of it

Comment: Could you include how to clean it, or what to look for?

Comment: see additional info in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a common issue with this model. It appears because it runs hot, the video eventually fails. Here is some additional information for you on this with some possible fixes.

[HP DV9000 black screen fix video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnkQNmKauEc)

[Problem, Fixes and Workarounds with My DV9000](http://techmata.blogspot.com/2008/12/problems-fixes-and-workarounds-with-my.html)

[HP Pavilion dv9000 Boot / Display Issues](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/53192-2-pavilion-dv9000-boot-display-issues)